# How to double click using selenium with vb.net code? 4.0 framework

Tags: vb.net, selenium-webdriver, element, double-click

I do not know how to double click on an element in visual studio.net framework. I search the web and I get c# examples. I do not know that language. I am new to vb.net and want to learn more. I have used "dim action1 as new actions.action(diver)" in my code but I get and error BC30002: Type 'Actions.Action' is not defined." I have imports open.selenium.interactions.actions included but not sure where to go or how to resolve this error. I would also want to know how to properly code how to double-click in vb.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of VB.NET Selenium - double click

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Set up Chrome WebDriver
        Dim driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
        Dim driverOptions As New ChromeOptions()
        driverOptions.AddArgument("start-maximized") ' Optionally maximize the browser window
        Dim driver As New ChromeDriver(driverService, driverOptions)

        ' Navigate to the webpage
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com")

        ' Find the element you want to double click on
        Dim element As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("element_id"))

        ' Perform double click on the element
        Dim action As Actions = New Actions(driver)
        action.DoubleClick(element).Build().Perform()

        ' Close the browser
        driver.Quit()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: I got it to work. since I already had driver declared I just needed to use dim element as iwebelement = driver.findelement(by.xpath("xpath"))and dim action as actions = new actions(driver) then action.doubleclick(element).build().perfrom()